# TableLayoutPanel only shows one row

Tags: powershell, winforms

I'm building a dialog box with WinForms. I have a panel where I want 4 controls to be displayed in a grid. I'm using `TableLayoutPanel`.

I want the end result to look like this:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
$TableLayoutPanel = [System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel] @{
    AutoSize = $true
    Dock = [System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Fill
}
$TableLayoutPanel.Controls.AddRange(@($name, $email, $phone, $expiration))

$GroupBox = [System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox] @{
    Text = "Point of Contact"
}
$GroupBox.Controls.Add($TableLayoutPanel)
```

This looks like this:

[image]

If I set the `ColumnCount` to 2, it looks like this:

[image]

Great, that's what I want. But then when I set the `RowCount` to 2, it looks like this:

[image]

No difference. So what's the right way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I set `AutoSize = $true` for all the controls within the `TableLayoutPanel`, it worked as intended:

[image]